# Database visible, but "not defined" in mongos

Tags: mongodb

In my cluster, I am running a single `mongod` shard (not a replica set), 1 `configsvr` for demo purposes and of course, the `mongos`. The `mongod` database and collection is accessible in the `mongos`, I can run `stats()` on it.

However, `sh.enableSharding(week6)` returns `2015-02-18T12:48:24.017+0800 ReferenceError: week6 is not defined`.

`sh.addShard("localhost:27018")` returns  `"errmsg" : "can't add shard localhost:27018 because a local database 'blog' exists in another shard0000:localhost:27018"`.

How do I delete the old shard on this port? Why just one shard per port allowed?

Answer (score 0):

The first error is a javascript error - the variable `week6` is not defined. You probably meant the string `"week6"`.

For the second error, it looks like you're trying to add the same shard twice. It's not just that they have the same port.